# ERR_ENCRYPTION_FAILED with libp2p connecting to kubo-ipfs

Tags: libp2p, ipfs-kubo

I’m getting `ERR_ENCRYPTION_FAILED` when trying to connect from my node app using js-libp2p v1.2.1 to a kubo-ipfs node v0.27. Se below for details information, code and config settings.

If I initialize my app in a remote location, I’m able to connect. I other words: libp2p to libp2p connections works. But the problem appear when I try to connect my app using libp2p to an existing cluster of nodes, or node, running kubo-ipfs.

libp2p settings

```js
export const libp2pOptions = {
  addresses: {
    listen,
  },
  transports: [
    webSockets({
      filter: all,
    }),
    circuitRelayTransport({
      discoverRelays: 1,
    }),
    tcp(),
  ],
  connectionEncryption: [noise()],
  streamMuxers: [yamux()],
  connectionGater: {
    denyDialMultiaddr: () => false,
  },
  services: {
    identify: identify(),
    pubsub: gossipsub({ allowPublishToZeroPeers: true }),
  },
  peerDiscovery: [
    mdns({ interval: 1000 }),
    bootstrap({
      list,
      timeout: 1000, // in ms,
      tagName: 'bootstrap',
      tagValue: 50,
      tagTTL: 120000, // in ms
    }),
  ],
};
```

connection logic

```js
import { createLibp2p } from 'libp2p'; // import the libp2p module
import { LevelBlockstore } from 'blockstore-level’;
import { createHelia } from 'helia’;
import { libp2pOptions } from './libp2pConfig.js’;

const blockstore = new LevelBlockstore(blockstorePath);
const libp2p = await createLibp2p(libp2pOptions);
  
let ipfs = await createHelia({ libp2p, blockstore });
let node = ipfs.libp2p;

const remoteMultiaddr = `/ip4/${PEER_IP}/tcp/${PEER_PORT}/ws/p2p/${PEER_ID}`;
const multiAddr = multiaddr(remoteMultiaddr);
  try {
      const { status, remoteAddr, remotePeer, direction } = await node.dial(
        multiAddr
      );
      console.log({ status, remoteAddr, remotePeer, direction });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
 
  node.addEventListener('peer:discovery', (evt) => {
    logger.info(`discovered peer ${evt.detail.id.toString()}`);
  });

  node.addEventListener('peer:connect', (evt) => {
    logger.info(`connected to ${evt.detail.toString()}`);
  });
```

Remote node running kubo ipfs config:

```bash
developer@ipfs-node-1beta:/home/msalimbene$ ipfs version
ipfs version 0.27.0
developer@ipfs-node-1beta:/home/msalimbene$ ipfs config show
{
  "API": {
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": [
        "PUT",
        "POST"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
        "http://localhost:3000",
        "http://127.0.0.1:5001"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Addresses": {
    "API": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001",
    "Announce": null,
    "AppendAnnounce": null,
    "Gateway": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080",
    "NoAnnounce": null,
    "Swarm": [
      "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/4001",
      "/ip6/::/tcp/4001",
      "/ip4/0.0.0.0/udp/4001/quic-v1",
      "/ip4/0.0.0.0/udp/4001/quic-v1/webtransport",
      "/ip6/::/udp/4001/quic-v1",
      "/ip6/::/udp/4001/quic-v1/webtransport"
    ]
  },
  "AutoNAT": {},
  "Bootstrap": [
    "/ip4/10.128.0.2/tcp/4001/p2p/QmVKuLVFyBX2ZSyB2w7YLpH4AM7YCdaqdNRjwZa9cR335M"
  ],
  "DNS": {
    "Resolvers": null
  },
  "Datastore": {
    "BloomFilterSize": 0,
    "GCPeriod": "1h",
    "HashOnRead": false,
    "Spec": {
      "mounts": [
        {
          "child": {
            "path": "blocks",
            "shardFunc": "/repo/flatfs/shard/v1/next-to-last/2",
            "sync": true,
            "type": "flatfs"
          },
          "mountpoint": "/blocks",
          "prefix": "flatfs.datastore",
          "type": "measure"
        },
        {
          "child": {
            "compression": "none",
            "path": "datastore",
            "type": "levelds"
          },
          "mountpoint": "/",
          "prefix": "leveldb.datastore",
          "type": "measure"
        }
      ],
      "type": "mount"
    },
    "StorageGCWatermark": 90,
    "StorageMax": "10GB"
  },
  "Discovery": {
    "MDNS": {
      "Enabled": true,
      "Interval": 10
    }
  },
  "Experimental": {
    "FilestoreEnabled": false,
    "Libp2pStreamMounting": false,
    "OptimisticProvide": false,
    "OptimisticProvideJobsPoolSize": 0,
    "P2pHttpProxy": false,
    "QUIC": false,
    "ShardingEnabled": false,
    "StrategicProviding": false,
    "UrlstoreEnabled": false
  },
  "Gateway": {
    "APICommands": [],
    "DeserializedResponses": null,
    "DisableHTMLErrors": null,
    "ExposeRoutingAPI": null,
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": [
        "X-Requested-With",
        "Range"
      ]
    },
    "NoDNSLink": false,
    "NoFetch": false,
    "PathPrefixes": [],
    "PublicGateways": null,
    "RootRedirect": "",
    "Writable": false
  },
  "Identity": {
    "PeerID": "12D3KooWGnC5m82ccmXayxe5qYtH1PupxuXtZpWEe2swTPfbn4Bk"
  },
  "Internal": {},
  "Ipns": {
    "RecordLifetime": "",
    "RepublishPeriod": "",
    "ResolveCacheSize": 128
  },
  "Migration": {
    "DownloadSources": null,
    "Keep": ""
  },
  "Mounts": {
    "FuseAllowOther": false,
    "IPFS": "/ipfs",
    "IPNS": "/ipns"
  },
  "Peering": {
    "Peers": null
  },
  "Pinning": {},
  "Plugins": {
    "Plugins": null
  },
  "Provider": {
    "Strategy": ""
  },
  "Pubsub": {
    "DisableSigning": false,
    "Router": "",
    "StrictSignatureVerification": false
  },
  "Reprovider": {},
  "Routing": {
    "AcceleratedDHTClient": false,
    "Methods": null,
    "Routers": null
  },
  "Swarm": {
    "AddrFilters": null,
    "ConnMgr": {},
    "DisableBandwidthMetrics": false,
    "DisableNatPortMap": false,
    "DisableRelay": false,
    "EnableRelayHop": false,
    "RelayClient": {},
    "RelayService": {},
    "ResourceMgr": {},
    "Transports": {
      "Multiplexers": {},
      "Network": {},
      "Security": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I’ve tried different encryption settings on my side (libp2p) and I get different errors under code `ERR_ENCRYPTION_FAILED`, see below:

- Trying with no encryption method I get `CodeError: At least one protocol must be specified` which makes sense:

```bash
CodeError: At least one protocol must be specified
    at DefaultUpgrader._encryptOutbound (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/libp2p/dist/src/upgrader.js:520:19)
    at async DefaultUpgrader.upgradeOutbound (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/libp2p/dist/src/upgrader.js:199:21)
    at async TCP.dial (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/@libp2p/tcp/dist/src/index.js:79:22)
    at async DefaultTransportManager.dial (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/libp2p/dist/src/transport-manager.js:81:20)
    at async queue.add.peerId.peerId [as fn] (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/libp2p/dist/src/connection-manager/dial-queue.js:154:38)
    at async raceSignal (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/race-signal/dist/src/index.js:28:16)
    at async Job.run (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/@libp2p/utils/dist/src/queue/job.js:56:28) {
  code: 'ERR_ENCRYPTION_FAILED',
  props: {}
}
```

using i `connectionEncryption: [noise()]` get `CodeError: read ECONNRESET`

```bash
CodeError: read ECONNRESET
    at DefaultUpgrader._encryptOutbound (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/libp2p/dist/src/upgrader.js:520:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async DefaultUpgrader.upgradeOutbound (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/libp2p/dist/src/upgrader.js:199:21)
    at async TCP.dial (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/@libp2p/tcp/dist/src/index.js:79:22)
    at async DefaultTransportManager.dial (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/libp2p/dist/src/transport-manager.js:81:20)
    at async queue.add.peerId.peerId [as fn] (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/libp2p/dist/src/connection-manager/dial-queue.js:154:38)
    at async raceSignal (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/race-signal/dist/src/index.js:28:16)
    at async Job.run (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/@libp2p/utils/dist/src/queue/job.js:56:28) {
  code: 'ERR_ENCRYPTION_FAILED',
  props: {}
}
```

and using `connectionEncryption: [plaintext()]` I get `CodeError: message length length too long`

```bash
CodeError: message length length too long
    at DefaultUpgrader._encryptOutbound (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/libp2p/dist/src/upgrader.js:520:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async DefaultUpgrader.upgradeOutbound (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/libp2p/dist/src/upgrader.js:199:21)
    at async TCP.dial (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/@libp2p/tcp/dist/src/index.js:79:22)
    at async DefaultTransportManager.dial (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/libp2p/dist/src/transport-manager.js:81:20)
    at async queue.add.peerId.peerId [as fn] (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/libp2p/dist/src/connection-manager/dial-queue.js:154:38)
    at async raceSignal (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/race-signal/dist/src/index.js:28:16)
    at async Job.run (file:///Users/salimbene/dev/ipfs/node_modules/@libp2p/utils/dist/src/queue/job.js:56:28) {
  code: 'ERR_ENCRYPTION_FAILED',
  props: {}
}
```